# How to convert an integer (time) to format HH:MM:SS in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, time

I have a table with a Time column (Data Type is int). Now i need to convert the integer value to Time Format HH:MM:SS (To show time on report) in SQL Server 2008.

Please help me on this.

Examples of Data in Time Column: 2412 and 84717 etc ..

**Note:** I don't know which format of time they have used in it. And i also don't want to update the format ,i just need to convert it to display on report.